# d3 js how to select from selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can someone help me with subselection in D3?
I have such html code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="fav">Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fav">Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fav">Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and js

```
var rows = d3.selectAll("td");
//then doing some data population
```

and then I need sleect all

```
<td class="fav">Data 1</td>
```

from `rows` in order to do another manipulation.

What is the way to do it?
I tried `rows.selectAll('.fav')` but it doesn't work for me.

p.s. `d3.selectAll(".fav")` is not an option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter method for this:

```
rows.filter(".fav");
```

will select(filter) the rows with `fav` class

Demo: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xng3hg37/)

Comment: Ok I found))) Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @echonax answer is selecting all `td` with a .fav class:

```
var subSelection = d3.selectAll("td.fav");
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79ncb6mg/